# How do I process a <div> as a form <input>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

What I've done is:

HTML

```
<form>
    <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" name="textBox"><?php echo $storyText; ?>
    </div>
    <textarea id="hiddeninput" name="hiddeninput"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$('#save').click(function () {
    var mysave = $('#textBox').html();
    $('#hiddeninput').val(mysave);
    $("form:first").submit();
    $('#hiddeninput').append(mysave);
    alert($('#hiddeninput').val());
});
```

So both the alert and the append display the correct information, but it won't save #hiddeninput as a php variable when I submit. Originally I had this as an hidden input method, but I'm trying to show that it won't post no matter what I do,

Comment: What's your question? And what's `submit()`?

Comment: This looks really ugly as I've been messing with it a lot. I just can't figure out how to submit DIV html as a form value. That's all I want.

Comment: What happened to the `form` tags?

Comment: You can't. A `div` isn't part of a form in that sense. Use a `textarea`.

Comment: @ahren That's what the jQuery code is trying to do: move the div contents into a textarea.

Comment: I can't use textarea. I'm using rich text editing.

Comment: I'm showing textarea instead of an input tag to show that it will append the correct information. I'm trying to move the div content to a hidden input field and submit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code is working almost as it is. 
But I'd rather use normal `<input type="hidden">` and you don't need to trigger `submit` for your form in your case just put the value in a hidden field.

Given your markup, with slight modifications

```
<form action="showrequest.php">
<div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" name="textBox" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
</div>
<textarea id="hiddeninput" name="hiddeninput"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $('#save').click(function () {
        var mysave = $('#textBox').html();
        $('#hiddeninput').val(mysave);
    });
});
```

`var_dump($_REQUEST)` on php side gives

```
array(2) {
  ["hiddeninput"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["save"]=>
  string(6) "Submit"
}
```

Comment: Thank You! After sleeping on this some I put the code in the header instead of in the body of the html markup which seems to have made all the difference in the world. I feel silly.

Comment: Try 1) add an id attr to the form tag, 2) changing your `type="submit"` to `type="button"`, 3) in the `.click()` after setting the hiddeninput value, add `$("#myForm").submit();` (also note: your hidden textarea will strip any formatting, while using hidden input will retain - whichever you need)

Answer (score 6):

Try binding the submit event instead of the click event.  What might be happending is the form is submitting before the value of your textarea is set.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var mysave = $('#textBox').html();
    $('#hiddeninput').val(mysave);
});
```

I tested this example with method="get" and got the html from the div to show up in the URL.

Comment: Nice!! Now I just need to find out why it's not working for me. This is awesome. I'll test more and let you know, but I think you are on the right track. Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm almost to the point where I'm going to log every change to the contenteditble div and move it to the hidden input field well before I submit the data. That just seems like an overkill though.

Comment: If I was you I would loose the form and just post with an ajax call.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your form is being submitted before your js code has a chance to run. Since you're submitting manually from jQuery, try preventing the default event of the button (which also submits the form):

```
$('#save').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mysave = $('#textBox').html();
    $('#hiddeninput').val(mysave);
    $("form:first").submit();
});
```

Comment: I agree, but that still doesn't seem to work. I'm dumbfounded at this point. There is no reason when both append and alert will show the correct information, but when submitting it doesn't post the content. Maybe I need to sleep on this.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking only from experience, you can't submit a `div` value in a form `POST`.

You can change it to a textarea, and if you want to restrict users from editing it, set it to `disabled`.

Alternatively, you can use javascript to submit the form, and pull the value from `#hiddeninput` that way.

Comment: Correct, but I first appended the value of the id hiddeninput. I was trying to show that it appends and alerts correctly but still won't submit.

Comment: btw... The code above is using Javascript to submit the form and I'm trying to transfer the html from #textBox to #hiddeninput,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic way to submit any div content elements you want (see notes below):

```
<form method="post" id="f">
<div id="txt" addToForm="f" contenteditable spellcheck="true" style="height:100px;width:300px;font-family:arial,sans serif;border:1px solid black;font-weight:normal;overflow-y:auto;"
></div><br />
<input type="button" value="Go" id="btnGo">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnGo").click(function(){
        $("div[addToForm]").each(function(){
            var tId=$(this).prop("id");
            $(this).after("<input type='hidden' name='"+tId+"' id='hdn"+tId+"'>");
            $("#hdn"+tId).val($(this).html());
        });
        ("#f").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Note 1) using `<input type="hidden">` preserves any formatting (IE11 allows more than FF). If you'd rather strip all formatting out, including CFLFs (i.e., `<br>`'s) from users hitting Enter/Return, use `<textarea style="display:none;"></textarea>` instead.
Note 2) be sure validation is successfully complete first or you will end up with multiple inputs with the same names.

Comment: Well it's too complicated than those which are upside

Comment: Granted it is a lot more code but gives a dynamic way to have multiple formatable pseudo-inputs. I was not claiming mine to be a best answer, just something more robust without having to trial-and-error to get it going.