# Post an HTML table (not a form) from a Jquery mobile app to a PHPMailer

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a mobile app that connects to a PHPmailer for a form submission. That works fine for the input form elements (name, email, etc), but I would also like to include a table (a table that is created in the app) that would be posted to the html body of the email. I can successfully get the table into a string with the ajax code below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    function submitData(id, url) {

    var content = $('#' + id).html();

$.ajax({
    'url' : url,
    'type' : "POST",
    'data': 'content=' + encodeURI(content)       
 });
}

$("#exportBtn").on("click", function () {

    submitData('export', 'http://mydomain.com/export.php');
  });

});
```

When I click the export, of course it doesn't go to the php for me to see if it works. The PHP file right now just contains an echo $content just to see if the post works (not sure if that is how the post variable is being set, either).

Questions: 1. How do I make the ajax request open the php page (like it does on a submit button to see the results?
2. Can I insert the ajax posted content into the HTMLBody of the php mailer.
3. How can I include the value from 'email' form input along with the ajax post of the Table?

Sorry for the basic questions or if I use the wrong terms--just a hobbyist here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Easy when you know what you're are looking for. Copied the div contents to an hidden input and just posted that. Got answer from here : [How do I process a <div> as a form <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538225/submit-div-as-form-value)

```
  $('#exportBtn').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var mysave = $('#textBox').html();
     $('#hiddeninput').val(mysave);
      $("form:first").submit();
});
```